# How to create Review charts like in playstore or amazon android app?

Tags: android, charts

I'm developing an android app which gets the user reviews like Google play app or amazon app. I need to display the review summary just like the way those application do. I wonder weather there is a inbuilt support to achieve that or have to use a library. Can anyone suggest me a mechanism?
Thanks in advance.!

This is a image of what im looking for [ From Google play]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use google chart api below link provide u some example

http://psychopyko.com/tutorial/how-to-use-google-charts/

Comment: Thanx for the reply, Im will try to adopt this to my application